# Microsoft.Azure.Mobile Namespace Issue [UWP]

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, nuget-package

Once I had a problem with **Microsoft.Azure.Mobile** NuGet package but somehow figured it out. Last night, I repaired my Visual Studio and the error has came back and I couldn't fix it.

I've installed Microsoft.Azure.Mobile package but using statements give error.

> The type or namespace name 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I guess I have to install something like extension or SDK I don't know but can't find solution on any documentation. Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried everythings with assist of tech guy from Microsoft. Repaired VS, deleted all cache and local data of NuGet and VS but didn't fix. At the end of way I removed bin and obj folders. That's fixed it. I don't know how or why but I don't care.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I checked this issue. I found the [Microsoft.Azure.Mobile 0.14.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile/) just has the dependencies as follows:

> **UAP 10.0**
>
> [Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform/) (>= 5.2.2)
>
> [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) (>= 6.0.1)
>
> [sqlite-net-pcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/) (>= 1.3.1)

I created my UWP app targeting version Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10240) and I could install the package successfully. It seems your package has not been installed successfully and there be some dependencies could not be resolved. You need to check all packages you referenced and try to locate the cause. Also you could provide the `project.json` file or a sample project for us to reproduce this issue.

Comment: I've been talking with tech from MS but they couldn't fix my issue. They say it's about my environment. 

Github link => https://github.com/almorax/dota2-handbook-uwp
project.assets.json => https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuKhKYIaTnMtxqhur3GmlR7YO68nPQ